# JPEG image size reduction

Tags: thunderbird

How can I reduce JPEG size when sending multiple images as attachments with Thunderbird?

Answer (score 3):

I would consider a plugin like [Auto Resize Image](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/auto-resize-image/).

Answer (score 0):

1. Nautilus has two great plugin which do this for you "nautilus-image-converter" and "nautilus-image-manipulator". After installation, you can access them by right click on image file in Nautilus.
2. Another option is "gimp", you can open your image with "gimp" and then save it as a jpg or something, with a lower quality.

Answer (score 0):

Beside Jonathans good answer,

alternatively, if you would like to let nautilus do the job (before sending by thunderbird) :

to resize Pics I found **imagemagick** [here](https://superuser.com/questions/87798/image-resizing-tool-for-ubuntu).
With **nautilus-image-converter** it is integrated in nautilus, so you would be able to resize pics in a batch by right-click in nautilus and have the resized pics on your system.

Kind regards